# how to attribute to navigation (<ul><li>) from an xml source navigation

Tags: zend-framework

HI,

my xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>HOME</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </home>

    <aboutus>
        <label>ABOUT US</label>
        <controller>about-us</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </aboutus>

    <destination>
        <label>DESTINATION</label>
        <controller>destination</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </destination>

</nav>
</config>
```

for code in my layout.phtml file

```
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/clientnav.xml', 'nav');
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $this->navigation()->setContainer($container);
    echo $this->navigation();
```

i get the result

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active">
    <a href="/globaltours.com/public/">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>

    <a href="/globaltours.com/public/about-us">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but i want the result

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active">
    <a href="/globaltours.com/public/">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li classs="sep"></li>

    <li>

    <a href="/globaltours.com/public/about-us">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note the separator between two list. Help me out.

Comment: If the seperator is there just for visual effect ie it doesnt offer any semantic purpose, I'd consider revising your CSS instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you HAVE to have the `sep` there and you cannot amend your CSS as @trickwallett suggested then you can query the navigation directly and then iterate over it yourself. Note that if you do this you will need to apply your own ACL rules.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml');

$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);

$pages = $this->navigation($container)->findAllById("main");

foreach ($pages as $i => $page)
{
    if(!$page->getVisible())
        continue;

    echo $this->menu()->htmlify($page);
}
```

There I use `findAllById()` but there are many others [documented here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html)